# The kubernetes "AVAILABLE" column indicates "0", but the former steps(in Kubernetes guide) are OK

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04, service-not-available

I need to deploy some docker images, and manage them with the Kubernetes.

I followed the tutorial"Interactive Tutorial - Deploying an App"(https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/deploy-app/deploy-interactive/).

But after I typing the command `kuberctl get deployments`, in the result table, the **deployment** column shows **0** instead of **1**, it's confusing me.

If there is anyone kindly guides me what's going wrong and what shall I do?

The OS is Ubuntu16.04;

The `kuberctl version` command shows the server and client version informations well.

The docker image is tagged already(a mysql:5.7 image).

```
devserver:~$ kubectl version　　　　

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.0", GitCommit:"ddf47ac13c1a9483ea035a79cd7c10005ff21a6d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-12-03T21:04:45Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}　　
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.0", GitCommit:"fc32d2f3698e36b93322a3465f63a14e9f0eaead", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-26T16:44:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}


devserver:~$ kubectl get deployments

NAME 　DESIRED　CURRENT　UP-TO-DATE　AVAILABLE　AGE
ap-mysql  　　１　　　　１　　　　１　　　　　　　０　　　　    １
hello-node　　１　　　　１　　　　１　　　　　　　０    　　　　１
```

I expect the answer about the phenomenon and the resolution. And I need to deploy my image on the minikube.

Answer (score 0):

Katacoda uses hosted VM's so sometimes it may be slow to respond to the terminal input.

To verify if any deployment is present you may run `kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces`.
To see what's going on with your deployment you can run `kubectl describe DEPLOYMENT_NAME -n NAMESPACE`.
To inspect a pod you can do the same `kubectl describe POD_NAME -n NAMESPACE`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd tried the commands, but it seems can't help...　　
　By the way, sorry I don't know how to paste text in code type.....

Comment: Were you able to properly create a deployment?